# ¿Por que al abrir mi pagina html, no me carga las imagenes o el video de mi slider hasta que no le doy al botón de siguiente imagen?

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image: Primera imagen de como abro la pagina]

[image: Captura de cuando pulso los 3 botones y me carga la imagen]

Estas son las imagenes y aqui esta el html del slider con sus clases:

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

// Next/previous controls
function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

// Thumbnail image controls
function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}
```

```css
* {box-sizing:border-box}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

/* Hide the images by default */
.mySlides {
  display: none;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 300px;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -22px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
  background-color: transparent;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.prev{
    left: 0;
}
.next {
  right: 0;
  /* border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px; */
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
/* .prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
} */

/* Caption text */
.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active, .dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4}
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4}
  to {opacity: 1}
}
```

```html
<div class="slideshow-container">
    <div class="mySlides fade">
      <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
      <video controls autoplayed src="../video/Duko.mp4" type=video/mp4 style="width:100%">
        <!-- <div class="text">Caption Three</div> -->
    </div>
    <!-- Full-width images with number and caption text -->
    <div class="mySlides fade">
      <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
      <img
        src="https://www.lamborghini.com/sites/it-en/files/DAM/lamborghini/facelift_2019/model_gw/images-s/2021/07_07/gate_family_s_02_m.jpg"
        style="width:100%">
      <!-- <div class="text">Caption Text</div> -->
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides fade">
      <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
      <img src="../images/paisaje2.jpg" style="width:100%">
      <!-- <div class="text">Caption Two</div> -->
    </div>



    <div style="text-align:center;">
      <button class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></button>
      <button class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></button>
      <button class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></button>
    </div>
```

este es el css del slider para que pueda cambiar de imagen dandole a la flecha de la derecha o de la izquierda respectivamente:

```
* {box-sizing:border-box}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

/* Hide the images by default */
.mySlides {
  display: none;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 300px;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -22px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
  background-color: transparent;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.prev{
    left: 0;
}
.next {
  right: 0;
  /* border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px; */
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
/* .prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
} */

/* Caption text */
.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active, .dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4}
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4}
  to {opacity: 1}
}
```

este es el js con todas las funciones para que pueda cambiar de imagen al pulsar tanto en las flechas de la izquierda y la derecha como en los botones de abajo

```
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

// Next/previous controls
function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

// Thumbnail image controls
function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }`introducir el código aquí`
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}
```

Todo esto ha sido usado de w3schools pero me da ese probelma cuando lo cargo en mi pagina web mientras que cuando lo pruebo en w3schools funciona perfecto

Comment: Fíjate bien en la direccion `src` de tus imágenes. Porque la foto del auto carga bien porque la dirección está bien. Sin embargo, la dirección de los demás no está bien. Aunque sea local, la dirección está mal

Comment: Si las pongo de internet, deberian de cargar todas bien no?

Comment: No. Cuando se trata de internet, la dirección debe ser online

Comment: Lo he probado con imagenes todas de internet, no me cargan tampoco y estoyc conectado a internet

Comment: Eso es raro. Verifica bien la dirección. A mí me funciona bien

Comment: Mira , esta es la direcction que tengo 
<div class="mySlides fade">
            <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
            <img src="https://www.lamborghini.com/sites/it-en/files/DAM/lamborghini/facelift_2019/model_gw/images-s/2021/07_07/gate_family_s_02_m.jpg"
                style="width:100%">
            <!-- <div class="text">Caption Text</div> -->
        </div>

Comment: Jamás ni nunca es imposible que funcione así. Si la imagen está en internet, la dirección debe comenzar con `https://`, tal cual como está en la foto del automovil

Comment: Si esta con https lo que no se es por que aqui sale asi. Si al pulsar en los botones de abajo me cargan las imagenes pero cuando cargo las imagenes no me carga ninguna de las imagenes hasta que le doy a uno de los botones. De todas formas si me pasas tu discord, y asi te paso alguna imagen  o los archivos para ver si a ti te funciona con mi codigo?